# pop up message when user has registered successfully

Tags: java, jsp, popup

This is my register.jsp page. 
Here is where I validate the form using javascript

```
  <script>
        function validateForm()
        {

            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["firstname"].value;
            if (x === null || x === "")
            {
                alert("First name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }

            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["lastname"].value;
            if (x === null || x === "")
            {
                alert("Second name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }

            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
            if (x === null || x === "")
            {
                alert("User name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }

            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
            if (x === null || x === "")
            {
                alert("Password must be filled out");
                return false;
            }


            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
            for (var i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {

                if (username[i] === newName)

                {

                    alert("USER");

                    success = false;

                    //stop further program execution

                    return false;

                }
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Here is the form the user fills in.

### Register Here:

```
            <form class="form" name="myForm" id="loginForm" action="regServlet" method="doPost" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >

                <p class="contact">
                <label class="description" for="element_1">First Name </label></p>
                <input id="name" name="firstname"  placeholder="Firstname" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 


                <br>

                <p class="contact">
                <label class="description" for="element_2">Last Name </label></p>

                <input id="element_2" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 



                <br>
                <p class="contact">
                <label class="description" for="element_3">UserName </label></p>

                <input id="element_3" name="username" placeholder="Username"class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" onblur="varify();"/><span id="res"></span> 


                <br>
                <p class="contact">
                <label class="description" for="element_4">Password </label></p>

                <input id="element_4" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="element text medium" type="password" maxlength="255" value=""/> 



                <br>
                <p class="contact">
                <label class="description" for="element_9">Email </label></p>
                <input id="element_9" name="email"  placeholder="E-mail" class="element text medium" type="email" maxlength="255" value=""/> 


                <p> Press To Submit </p>


                <input id="loginButton" class="uname" type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
                <input type="submit" value="register" />
                </ul>
            </form>
```

I want to be able to have a pop up saying the user has successfully registered. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet you can set a request attribute and then forward back to the register.jsp page where you can recover it and show the pop-up